# Strip root directory with unpack-dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a third-party archive ([IntelliJ IDEA CE](https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-14.1.4.tar.gz) in my case) that has a root directory whose name I cannot guess. In the `unpack-dependencies` task, how can I unpack the archive without the root directory?

Currently all files from the archive are extracted into

```
testproject/target/dependency/IntelliJ-IDEA-CE/idea-IC-141.1532.4/
```

but I want them to be extracted into just

```
testproject/target/dependency/IntelliJ-IDEA-CE/
```

but keep the subdirectory tree.

It would be similar to doing the following on the command line:

```
cd testproject/target/dependency/IntelliJ-IDEA-CE/
tar -xvf ideaIC-14.1.4.tar.gz --strip 1
```

I've already installed the archive in my local repository. This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.virtlink</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jetbrains.intellij-ce</artifactId>
            <version>14.1.4</version>
            <type>tar.gz</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unzip-distribution</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeArtifactIds>org.jetbrains.intellij-ce</includeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency/IntelliJ-IDEA-CE</outputDirectory>
                            <includes>**/*.jar</includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <extdirs>${project.build.directory}/dependency/IntelliJ-IDEA-CE/lib/</extdirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This looks so specific, command-line/filesystem oriented and out of the `maven-dependency-plugin` capabilities that I would certainly head toward something around the `maven-ant-plugin` or `maven-exec-plugin`.

Comment: @Tome: As many archives have a root directory, I hoped `maven-dependency-plugin` provided some sort of switch or include statement that I could use to skip the root directory. I don't necessarily want to use the `tar` command, it was just an example.

Comment: There is nothing in the `maven-dependency-plugin` for that, and I don't think that other plugins such as `truezip-maven-plugin` can help neither. As far as I can see, you will end up either unpacking somewhere then _moving_ the subcontents somewhere else or invoking Ant/executable directly.